# How to find the difference between two JSONs in java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have 2 large JSONs with nested elements and I need to find the difference of these jsons. Each Json represents the data from LDAP in different days. I was looking into Jackson's JsonNode class. Equals method of this class can compare 2 JsonNodes but it doesn't return the difference.

Appreciate any input on what would be best approach to get the difference of 2 JSONs. It will be great if anyone has sample code for the same. Thanks.

### JSON1

```
 {
    "id": "_6MrXgEx7Ee6GUol3yT5KIw",
    "name": "test",
    "fullName": "I_EXT_TEST",
    "members": [
        {
            "mail": null,
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "Author"
                },
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "Commenter"
                }
            ],
            "dng_ID": "aa@yy.com",
            "ad_ID": "CN=aaaaaaaaaa"
        },
        {
            "mail": null,
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "Author"
                }
            ],
            "dng_ID": "bb@yy.com",
            "ad_ID": "CN=bbbbbbbbbbb"
        },
        {
            "mail": null,
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "Commenter"
                }
            ],
            "dng_ID": "cc@yy.com",
            "ad_ID": "CN=ccccccc"
        },
        {
            "mail": null,
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "Commenter"
                }
            ],
            "dng_ID": "dd@yy.com",
            "ad_ID": "CN=ddddddd"
        },
    ]
}
```

### JSON2

```
{
    "id": "_6MrXgEx7Ee6GUol3yT5KIw",
    "name": "test",
    "fullName": "I_EXT_TEST",
    "members": [
        {
            "mail": null,
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "Commenter"
                }
            ],
            "dng_ID": "cc@yy.com",
            "ad_ID": "CN=ccccccc"
        },
        {
            "mail": null,
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": null,
                    "name": "Commenter"
                }
            ],
            "dng_ID": "dd@yy.com",
            "ad_ID": "CN=ddddddd"
        },
    ]
}
```

### Expected Output

```
"members": [
            {
                "mail": null,
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "id": null,
                        "name": "Author"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": null,
                        "name": "Commenter"
                    }
                ],
                "dng_ID": "aa@yy.com",
                "ad_ID": "CN=aaaaaaaaaa"
            },
            {
                "mail": null,
                "roles": [
                    {
                        "id": null,
                        "name": "Author"
                    }
                ],
                "dng_ID": "bb@yy.com",
                "ad_ID": "CN=bbbbbbbbbbb"
            }
     ]
}
```

Comment: ChatGPT has returned this code to compare the 2 JSONNode objects using jackson. But this seems to be syntactically incorrect. Appreciate suggestions on how this should be changed to work.

private static JsonNode findJsonNodeDifferences(JsonNode node1, JsonNode node2) {
        // Use Jackson's JsonNode API to find the difference
        return JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode()
                .set("diff", JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode()
                        .set("node1", node1)
                        .set("node2", node2));
    }

Comment: Check out: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to get the difference between 2 json objects, not just comparing if they are equal or not.

Answer (score 0):

JSON library *Jossons & Josson* set operation on two datasets.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Deserialization**

```
Jossons jossons = new Jossons();
jossons.putDataset("JSON1", Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"id\": \"_6MrXgEx7Ee6GUol3yT5KIw\"," +
    "    \"name\": \"test\"," +
    "    \"fullName\": \"I_EXT_TEST\"," +
    "    \"members\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "            \"mail\": null," +
    "            \"roles\": [" +
    "                {" +
    "                    \"id\": null," +
    "                    \"name\": \"Author\"" +
    "                }," +
    "                {" +
    "                    \"id\": null," +
    "                    \"name\": \"Commenter\"" +
    "                }" +
    "            ]," +
    "            \"dng_ID\": \"aa@yy.com\"," +
    "            \"ad_ID\": \"CN=aaaaaaaaaa\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"mail\": null," +
    "            \"roles\": [" +
    "                {" +
    "                    \"id\": null," +
    "                    \"name\": \"Author\"" +
    "                }" +
    "            ]," +
    "            \"dng_ID\": \"bb@yy.com\"," +
    "            \"ad_ID\": \"CN=bbbbbbbbbbb\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"mail\": null," +
    "            \"roles\": [" +
    "                {" +
    "                    \"id\": null," +
    "                    \"name\": \"Commenter\"" +
    "                }" +
    "            ]," +
    "            \"dng_ID\": \"cc@yy.com\"," +
    "            \"ad_ID\": \"CN=ccccccc\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"mail\": null," +
    "            \"roles\": [" +
    "                {" +
    "                    \"id\": null," +
    "                    \"name\": \"Commenter\"" +
    "                }" +
    "            ]," +
    "            \"dng_ID\": \"dd@yy.com\"," +
    "            \"ad_ID\": \"CN=ddddddd\"" +
    "        }" +
    "    ]" +
    "}"));
jossons.putDataset("JSON2", Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"id\": \"_6MrXgEx7Ee6GUol3yT5KIw\"," +
    "    \"name\": \"test\"," +
    "    \"fullName\": \"I_EXT_TEST\"," +
    "    \"members\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "            \"mail\": null," +
    "            \"roles\": [" +
    "                {" +
    "                    \"id\": null," +
    "                    \"name\": \"Commenter\"" +
    "                }" +
    "            ]," +
    "            \"dng_ID\": \"cc@yy.com\"," +
    "            \"ad_ID\": \"CN=ccccccc\"" +
    "        }," +
    "        {" +
    "            \"mail\": null," +
    "            \"roles\": [" +
    "                {" +
    "                    \"id\": null," +
    "                    \"name\": \"Commenter\"" +
    "                }" +
    "            ]," +
    "            \"dng_ID\": \"dd@yy.com\"," +
    "            \"ad_ID\": \"CN=ddddddd\"" +
    "        }" +
    "    ]" +
    "}"));
```

**Subtract right from left**

```
JsonNode node = jossons.evaluateQuery("JSON1 <-< JSON2");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "members" : [ {
    "mail" : null,
    "roles" : [ {
      "id" : null,
      "name" : "Author"
    }, {
      "id" : null,
      "name" : "Commenter"
    } ],
    "dng_ID" : "aa@yy.com",
    "ad_ID" : "CN=aaaaaaaaaa"
  }, {
    "mail" : null,
    "roles" : [ {
      "id" : null,
      "name" : "Author"
    } ],
    "dng_ID" : "bb@yy.com",
    "ad_ID" : "CN=bbbbbbbbbbb"
  } ]
}
```